# Show that $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ is constant.

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $\left|f(x)-f(y)\right| \le \|x-y\|^2$ for every $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^2$. Show that $f$ is constant.

So I think that if $f$ is constant then $\nabla f \equiv 0$.

Let $(x_0, y_0) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. If $f$ is differentiable at this point then the following limit need to be zero:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(x_0,y_0)} \left| \frac{f(x,y) - f(x_0,y_0) - \langle \nabla f,(x-x_0,y-y_0)\rangle}{\|(x-x_0,y-y_0)\|} \right| = 0$$

We know that:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(x_0,y_0)} \left| \frac{f(x,y) - f(x_0,y_0) - \langle \nabla f,(x-x_0,y-y_0)\rangle}{\|(x-x_0,y-y_0)\|} \right| \le \lim_{(x,y)\to (x_0,y_0)} \left| \frac{\|(x-x_0,y-y_0)\|^2 - \langle \nabla f,(x-x_0,y-y_0)\rangle}{\|(x-x_0,y-y_0)\|} \right| $$

Where should I take it from here? I tried to develop it further but got stuck..

Comment: The denominatr should be $\|(x,y)-(x_0,y_0)\|$ to simulate differentiation.

Comment: I think you missed a squared in the second limit, $\|(x-x_0,y-y_0)\|^2$.

Comment: I've corrected both mistakes.

Comment: It also looks like the gradient is wrong.  Shouldn't it be $(x-x_0)$ in there as well?

Comment: Just divide by $||x-y||$ and take the limit $x\rightarrow y$.

Comment: Now you can break it up into a sum, where the first term approaches zero and you're left with the gradient part.

Comment: @MichaelBurr, How can I conclude that the limit is zero and the gradient is zero?

Comment: The function is differentiable if there is a choice for the gradient that makes the limit 0.  In this case, the choice for the gradient is the zero vector.  This simultaneously shows that the function is differentiable (because the limit is always 0) and that the gradient is 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't want to *assume* that $f$ is differentiable with some unknown derivative $\nabla f$ (or technically the transpose $(\nabla f)'$). Rather, we're trying to *prove* that $f$ has a specific derivative, namely 0, which simply requires showing that the limit you wrote evaluates to zero which you substitute 0 in place of $\nabla f$.

Comment: If I substitute $\nabla f$ with $0$ I do get the limit is $0$. But it could be that for $\nabla f \ne 0$ the limit is also $0$. Couldn't it?

Comment: No, showing that the limit is 0 (when $\nabla f$ is replaced by 0)  proves that $f$ has 0 as a derivative, by the definition of the derivative. And it is a standard fact (which can easily be proven) that the derivative is unique.

Comment: Oh I see. You relying on the fact that $\nabla f$ is unique. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\bx}{\mathbf{x}}$In the spirit of being as "low-tech" as possible, let $\bx = (x, y)$ be arbitrary, and for each positive integer $n$ consider the points $\bx_{i} = (i/n)\bx$, $0 \leq i \leq n$. By hypothesis,
$$
\left|f(\bx_{i}) - f(\bx_{i-1})\right| \leq \|\bx_{i} - \bx_{i-1}\|^{2}
  = \frac{1}{n^{2}} \|\bx\|^{2},\quad 1 \leq i \leq n,
$$
so
$$
\left|f(\bx) - f(\bx_{0})\right|
  = \left| \sum_{i=1}^{n} f(\bx_{i}) - f(\bx_{i-1})\right|
  \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left|f(\bx_{i}) - f(\bx_{i-1})\right|
  \leq \frac{\|\bx\|^{2}}{n}.
$$
Since $n$ was arbitrary, $f(\bx) = f(\bx_{0}) = f(0, 0)$ for all $\bx$.